# Change All Properties In A Class To Have Backing Property With Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a simple POCO with 12 properties. I know that I can select a property, hit Alt-Enter and select "To property with backing field". Is there a way to automate this for every property in the class, or am I using the Resharper shortcut 12 times?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, There is no option to for your case. But, Resharper does provide options for applying quick-fixes on a wider scope.

for example, If when you change variable's datatype to var, you may apply that change everywhere in file/project/solution, if you wish.

For a full list of quick fixes that can be applied on a wider scope. Please check http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Fix_in_Scope.html

Answer (score -1):

it's just a 12 times key pressing using keyboard shortcuts.

And in some scenarios Fody could be used: http://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged